# Run private_pub and faye in Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, faye, private-pub

I'm following this Rails chat tutorial and successfully make it locally.
But I got trouble deploying it to Amazon EC2 Linux.
Error loading the faye.js

> > GET http://localhost:9292/faye.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Do I need to configure something ?
BTW I already added port 9292 for both Incoming and Outbound in Security Groups.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVE**

No need to add Inbound or Outbound in Amazon EC2 Security Group.
To run or check the faye connection like in local development (http://localhost:9292) in Amazon EC2.

**run/check faye**

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

-b is for binding.
See this link, https://github.com/thoughtbot/til/blob/master/docker/binding-to-0-0-0-0-in-rails.md

So, you can now access it using EC2 IP/Elastic IP like http://54.33.222.111:9292.

Then, you will see "Sure you're not looking for /faye ?"

**run private_pub**

```
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -o 0.0.0.0
```

-o will open ports for your EC2 IP Address.

> You can also use external faye server.
>   As here https://github.com/Hareramrai/fayeserver.
>   But it seems a little slow in response,  so I still used locally.

If you plan to use external faye server, update your private_pub.yml like:

```
server: "http://ramfayeserver.herokuapp.com/faye"
secret_token: "batkaro"
```